# Can anyone help me with the python web scraping, below is the code

Tags: python, html-table

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = requests.get('https://www.bacb.com/services/o.php?page=101127&by=state&state=CA&pagenum=3').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
type(soup)
print(soup.prettify())
table_rows = table.find_all('tr')
for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [i.text for i in td]
    print(row)
```

Comment: What't the problem/error?

Comment: Write `"html.parser"` instead of `"lxml"`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use regex later on the data

try this

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

html = requests.get('https://www.bacb.com/services/o.php? 
page=101127&by=state&state=CA&pagenum=3').text 
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
table_rows = soup.find_all('tr') 

for tr in table_rows: 
    td = tr.find_all('td') 
    row = [i.text for i in td] 
    print(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. Except that you used "table" instead of "Soup"(at 6th row).

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = requests.get('https://www.bacb.com/services/o.php?page=101127&by=state&state=CA&pagenum=3').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
# print(soup.prettify())
table_rows = soup.find_all('tr')
for tr in table_rows:
  td = tr.find_all('td')
  row = [i.text for i in td]
  print(row)
```